# Change current UITextView Writing Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to create a simple button with a 'bolding' function just like in the Apple Notes app. This would:

1. If text is selected either bold or unbold selected text.
2. If no text is selected change current writing attributes and also the icon of the button to denote wether you're typing in bold or not.

I am having trouble working out how to solve part 2. How can I go about working out and changing the current UITextView's writing attributes?

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    selectedRange = noteContents.selectedRange
}

func bold() {
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(attributedString: noteContents.attributedText)

    if let textRange = selectedRange {
        //If text is NOT selected
        switch textRange.length {
        case 0:

            //Work out current writing attributes and change them

        default:
            //If text IS selected
            print("Selected")
            print(textRange.length)
            //Enumerate all the fonts in the selectedRange
            attributedString.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: textRange, options: []) { (font, range, pointee) in
                let newFont: UIFont
                if let font = font as? UIFont {
                    var fontTraits = font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
                        //If selected text contains Bold
                    if fontTraits.contains(.traitBold) {
                        fontTraits.remove([.traitBold])
                        let fontAtrDetails = font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontTraits)
                        newFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: font.pointSize)
                    } else {
                        //If selected text does not contain Bold
                        fontTraits.insert([.traitBold])
                        let fontAtrDetails = font.fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(fontTraits)
                        newFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontAtrDetails!, size: font.pointSize)
                    }
                    noteContents.textStorage.addAttributes([.font : newFont], range: textRange)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as I remember textview has typingAttributes, you can change them on the flight

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik How can I change typingAttributes?

Comment: smth like this textView.typingAttributes = [.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)]

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you must configure bold button as indicate that button is selected or unselected .
in the bold button Action change attribute in the selected range this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/intro-text-kit-ios-programming-guide/) will be helpful